# difference between countUp() and countUp

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have a script that counts up the number in a box (actually, in this exercise -> http://jqexercise.droppages.com/#page_0022_ ) each 1 second like this.

```
var target = $("#target input");
var countUp = function(){
    target.val(parseInt(target.val())+1);   
        setTimeout(countUp,1000);          // this line
};

countUp();
```

My questions is, when i change `countUp` to `countUp()` at the line I marked with `// this line`, it instantly counts up to 15616. What is the difference between those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`countUp` references the function as an object. In JavaScript everything is an object, including functions, and can be passed around. `countUp()` calls the function `countUp` and returns its value.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `()` to the function invokes it instantly, while just using the function name is actually passing it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`countUp()` is a recursive invocation of the function. Each call to the function invokes it again (immediately), and the return value (which is `undefined`) is passed to setTimeout.

This would be an infinite loop, except I believe the exception from `setTimeout` receiving a non function is interrupting it after 1 second, leading to a stop at 15616.

Comment: @Ian I recall seeing something like "useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)" being thrown when I passed an integer to setTimeout.

Comment: You're quite right. I'm not sure what I was thinking of, so just ignore that :)

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the setTimeout(countUp, 1000); sets the time to execute the countup function in milliseconds seconds every nth second. Which in this case would be 1 second. countup is just being passed as a parameter into the setTimeout function here.