# jQuery function vs handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

A simple question from someone trying to learn:

I have this:

```
$(function(){$("#topFlag").hover(changeFlag, setFlag ); });

function changeFlag(){
  //some code
 };

 function setFlag(){
  //somecode
 };
```

And it's all working (now).  But what I expected to use was:

```
$(function(){$("#topFlag").hover(changeFlag(), setFlag() ); });
```

What's the difference?  Why doesn't `changeFlag()` (with the parens) work?  Isn't this a function call?  What if I wanted to pass a parameter to the function?

Thanks for any insights (or pointers to documentation I can read).  I've already checked out:

http://api.jquery.com/hover/
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568291/what-is-the-defference-between-calling-function-in-javascipt-with-or-without-par, Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949879/difference-between-countup-and-countup/16949950#16949950

Comment: Also, W3Schools is not the best resource... I'd recommend you check out the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript, you'll learn more and better there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`changeFlag` is a function.

`changeFlag()` calls that function.

You need to pass the function. You don't need to call the function and pass its `return` value.

Answer (score 3):

When you add braces after a function name , **it executes the function**

```
setFlag() ; // calls the function
```

But you want the function to fire , when you hover over the element

**And not at the time of attaching the event**

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the functions are also variables, when you pass it as a parameter you want to send the function to execute, if you write this `yourFunc()` you would be sending the result of that function instead.
To send parameter I use this:

```
$(function(){$("#topFlag").hover(function(){changeFlag(param1, param2,...)}, function(){setFlag(param1, param2,...)}); });
```

this creates an anonym function that call your functions.

Comment: You can avoid anonymous function like: `$.proxy(changeFlag, null, param1, param2)`